# javascript: поиск в массиве, компактный код

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка, поиск

Приветствую

у меня есть массив вида

```
let ranges = [
    {
        min: 10,
        max: 10,
    },
    {
        min: 30,
        max: 40,
    },
]
```

массив значений

```
let data = {
    10: {},
    17: {},
    32: {},
}
```

Нужно построить из массива data на основании данных из массива range новый массив:

```
let new_data = {
    10: {},
    32: {},
}
```

**Как это сделать красиво и оптимально, без большого кол-ва строчек кода?**

Сейчас сделал школьным методом в лоб:

```
let new_data = {};

for (const index in data)
{
    for (const range of ranges)
    {
        if ((index  >= range.min) && (index <= range.max))
        {
            new_data[index ] = articles[index ];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

А можно ли как-то сделать покрасивее код?
Уровня "в одну строчку" средствами JavaScript

Comment: У вас как-то странно, `ranges` - массив объектов, а вот `data` и `new_data` - объекты, уточните, что есть что?

Comment: Если `ranges` сортирован по `min`, если в нём нет наложений, если `data` сортирован по значению (ну всё как показано в примере) - то обычное однопроходное сравнение с двумя указателями.

Comment: @Sergey Glazirin, всё верно в `ranges` содержатся объекты-пары `{min, max}`, эти пары не отсортированы и в принципе допускается пересечение, например `[{min: 10, max: 20,}, {min: 15, max: 17,}]`, `data` и `new_data` - объекты (ассоциативные массивы), и на основании по сути правил, которые содержатся в `range` создается новый ассоциативный массив `new_data` на основании старого ассоциативного массива `data`

Comment: @Akina, внутри `range` никакой сортировки нет, ну только `min <= max` для каждого подобъекта

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В одну строчку:

```js
const ranges = [
    {
        min: 10,
        max: 10,
    },
    {
        min: 30,
        max: 40,
    },
];

const data = {
    10: {},
    17: {},
    32: {},
    33: {},
    41: {}
}


let new_data = Object.keys(data).filter(index => ranges.find(range => index >= range.min && index <= range.max)).reduce((new_data, index) => Object.assign(new_data, {[index]: data[index]}), {});

console.log(new_data);
```

Правда я не уверен что это красивее)

Comment: Да уж, про "в одну строку" я же фигурально :)

Тут  даже я про эффективность не уверен :)

Comment: @Zhihar быстродействие 100% быстрей в вашем варианте.